# Travelling to USA (NYC) from UK to see my daughter - what documentation is required?

Tags: usa, covid-19

My daughter is currently staying with family in US (she is US citizen, but normally lives in Brazil). I wish to travel to see her, but AA have not been able to confirm what I would have to take to prove I am the father of a US citizen. I am assuming copies of birth certificate and passport will suffice, but I don't like 'assuming' in this case given all the other hoops I need to jump though.

Also, am i allowed to quarantine with her and her uncles family or do I have to isolate?

Comment: Regarding the requirements for quarantine in NYC, see my recent answer over on [Law StackExchange](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/58498/self-quarantine-requirements-in-nyc/58506#58506).  My reading of how it applies to you is that you can stay with the family, but you have to have your own bedroom & bathroom in case you get sick, and you can't leave the apartment.

Comment: Is your daughter a minor?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't been following this very closely, but several months ago it was apparent that travelers trying to use ESTA to fly from Europe to the US were [having their ESTAs cancelled automatically](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/158884/19400) even if they were excepted from the public health restrictions.

You will therefore need to find out how to prove your relationship before you board, whether by getting your exempt status formally registered in the ESTA system or by getting a B-2 visa.  Once you've taken one of these steps with the US government, you can bring whatever documents you needed for that along with you to show to American Airlines.

If you already have a valid visa that was issued before the travel restrictions were imposed, you might want to ask the consulate what documents they would require to issue a visa now.

Comment: That is extremely helpful and more info than three airlines and the US consulate have given me. Appreciate the effort to reply, thank you!