# Entering USA as tourist after abandoning green card

Tags: usa, esta

I’ve seen similar questions but not sure if this has been answered. My husband is a U.K. national. We lived in the US for 6 years then due to my work, no longer reside in the US. We now reside in the U.K. as we knew my work wouldn’t allow us to to fully live in the states, my husband voluntarily abandoned his green card. We submitted the form i407 and the actual green card itself. We’ve received no confirmation or anything.now my question is we would like to visit my family in the states as due to Covid we’ve not seen any of my family in almost 2 years. Will my husband be able to use ESTA to enter? We tried to get an ESTA but it was not authorised. I can only assume this was due to his green card abandonment not fully being processed? Will future travel to the US be a problem? I’m a US citizen and our two children are also US citizens. Any info appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

> Will my husband be able to use ESTA to enter? We tried to get an ESTA but it was not authorised.

Since your husband has no ESTA, he cannot use ESTA to travel to the US.  The proper thing to do if ESTA authorization is denied is to apply for a B visa.  That's difficult to do at the moment, but it's the only option.

Comment: Thanks for that reply. We did think this would be the case. I wonder if in the future he’s be allowed to enter as tourist on Esta? Or is this no longer an option? I just don’t understand why that’s oils be as we did the right thing by abandoning green card.

Comment: @Yoko97 Without knowing his answers to the qualifying questions, it's hard to say for sure why his ESTA was refused, but in general being a former permanent resident is not disqualifying.  My guess is that it was refused because of COVID-19.  See for example https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/158875/19400

Comment: And, alas, an ESTA refusal is lifetime. Once you were refused you always need to ask for a visa thereon.

Comment: Really? So since we attempted it, even though in the past he has entered on the VWP, because this time was not authorized he will always need to apply for a visa? Thanks for any info.

Comment: @chx that is a common misconception.  Nobody knows what the ESTA refusal algorithm is, but a prior ESTA refusal isn't a statutory barrier to using the VWP.  It's entirely possible that a post-COVID application would succeed.

Comment: @phoog that is very interesting. I indeed can't find a source for this but I have thought even this site mentioned this quite a few times. https://web.archive.org/web/20190805181650/https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1097/~/previously-denied-a-visa-or-immigration-benefit "If you were previously denied a visa, or previously refused entry to the United States, or previously removed from the U.S., your ESTA application will most likely be denied." indeed that doesn't mention the ESTA... but it's not encouraging.