# Can I travel to the USA as a British citizen, along with my wife who is an American citizen?

Tags: usa, uk

We plan to book flights from 13 September 2021 to 24 September 2021 to the USA. This site: https://uk.usembassy.gov/visas/u-s-visa-and-travel-faqs/ states that you cannot enter the USA if you've been to one of the following countries in the last 14 days (of which the UK is one).

It also states:

The travel restriction does not apply to:

**U.S. citizens. (my wife)**

Legal permanent residents (LPRs).

**Most immediate family members of U.S. citizens. (myself, a spouse)**

Other individuals who are identified in the proclamation.

I am guessing I would need to bring our marriage certificate to prove we're married to each other. Are airlines up to date with these exemptions and do you know if I'm likely to run into issues?

It states here: https://uk.usembassy.gov/visas/u-s-visa-and-travel-faqs/ that "U.S. citizens residing in the United Kingdom are subject to the ‘Stay at Home’ regulations. You should not travel abroad unless it is permitted under the rules. This means you may not go on holiday."

I suspect we can travel since international travel is not permitted, with certain restrictions.

Secondly, we are flying into Detroit then driving down to Ohio. Where can I find information on whether I need to self isolate? If, for example, Michigan requires travellers to self-isolate but Ohio doesn't, could I land in Michigan then drive to Ohio, as it's my final destination?

A bit overwhelmed with all the travel guidance so would appreciate some help in getting put in the right direction with travel to the USA recently.

Thanks.

Comment: See https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/168008/travelling-to-the-us-as-a-spouse-of-a-us-citizen-with-esta-and-with-the-exemptio and https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/168153/30703

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Spouses of US citizens and permanent residents are one of the categories of people who are exempt from the geographic COVID-19 entry bans to the US. See for example the [text of the ban for UK and Ireland](https://www.federalregister.gov/documents/2020/03/18/2020-05797/suspension-of-entry-as-immigrants-and-nonimmigrants-of-certain-additional-persons-who-pose-a-risk-of).

Airlines should be aware of all the exceptions to the ban. Obviously the knowledge of individual airline staff members may vary, but the exceptions for relatives have been there since the beginning of the ban (it's not new), and spouses is the most obvious category of relatives that have exceptions, so it's very unlikely they would be unaware of it.

Yes, you would need to bring proof of your relationship to your wife, the US citizen (a marriage certificate should do), and proof of her US citizenship.

Comment: Would a photo of the marriage certificate work, instead of a physical copy?

Comment: @MasterPlanTakeo maybe.  If it doesn't, you'll lose your airfare.  I wouldn't risk it.  Also, don't try to check in online or your ESTA may be cancelled.  Check in at the airport and show the marriage certificate first.  See [Travelling to the US as the spouse of a citizen](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/168216/19400).

Comment: @MasterPlanTakeo I would clarify this with the airline. Probably safest bet to just take the original, that's what [I did](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/168008/travelling-to-the-us-as-a-spouse-of-a-us-citizen-with-esta-and-with-the-exemptio). Generally my impression was that the US has put the airlines in charge of most of the verification process (my marriage certificate wasn't even checked at the border). I flew with United Airlines and their staff seemed very aware of the rules. As phoog said, I checked in at the airport, but generally the process was smooth.